# Based on item in list, open file with similar name and append contents to df

Tags: python, regex

Given `myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and a folder full of files like

```
['a_3432.bed', 'a_4958.bed', 'b_3432.bed', 'b_4958.bed', 'c_3432.bed', 
'c_4958.bed', 'd_3432.bed', 'd_4958.bed', etc]
```

I want to open the files and append their contents to a dataframe based on each item in my list. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

for item in myList:
    open('a*.bed') as infile:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        for line in infile:
            df.append(line)
```

I have not used regular expressions, but I think they might be the key because I know they're used to recognize patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You want the standard `glob` module to find the matching files (glob patterns, like the one in your pseudocode, are similar to but not the same as regular expressions) and possibly `fileinput` to treat all of them together.